# div onclick breaks child radio checked behaviour

Tags: jquery, radio-button, checked

I collapse some divs and let users expand them and select radio/checkboxes.
I have this code and a simple jquery script. Trouble is the radio button checked behavior is broken by the onclick handler of its parent div.  Any ideas how I fix it?

```
    <div class="tree">
        <div class="parent">Item
           <div class="parent">ParentItem
              <div>
                 <input type="radio" name="_gen" value="a"></input>LeafItem a
              </div>
              <div>
                 <input type="radio" name="_gen" value="b"></input>LeafItem b
              </div>
         </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                $('div.tree div:has(div)').addClass('parent'); 
                $('div.tree div').click(function() {
                    var o = $(this);
                    o.children('div').toggle();
                    o.children($(':radio')).attr('checked', true);
                    o.filter('.parent').toggleClass('expanded');
                    return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Try to comment the `return false;` line.

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure what it is you're trying to do here, but stopping the propagation on the inputs will solve the issue with clicks registering on higher elements :

```
$(function() {
    $('div.tree div:has(div)').addClass('parent');
    $('div.tree div').click(function() {
        var o = $(this);
        o.children('div').toggle();
        o.children($(':radio')).attr('checked', true);
        o.filter('.parent').toggleClass('expanded');
        return false;
    });
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });​
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ejwn/)

Also, input tags are self closing, and does not need to be closed ?

Answer (score 0):

This is better according to me:

```
$('div.tree div:has(div)').addClass('parent');
$('div.tree div').click(function( e ) {
    if ( !$(e.target).hasClass("parent") ) {
        return;
    }
    var o = $(this);
    o.children('div').toggle();
    o.children($(':radio')).attr('checked', true);
    o.filter('.parent').toggleClass('expanded');
    return false;
});
```

This way you just have to create one *event* and then check the **target** in that event to see if it has a class called `.parent`.